# Dynamic id name based on model in jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, jcrop

I'm following [railscasts for jcrop](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised?view=asciicast) but was wondering how do I have a dynamic model name in jquery if I have something like this:

```
update: (coords) =>
  $('#user_crop_x').val(coords.x)
  $('#user_crop_y').val(coords.y)
  $('#user_crop_w').val(coords.w)
  $('#user_crop_h').val(coords.h)
  @updatePreview(coords)
```

`#user` is based on user's model, but it was hard coded, but if I have other models with cropping, how do you make the id dynamic based on the model?

Thanks

Comment: It's just a string, no? Get you get model name as a string?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for responding. I'm still new to rails, I'm not sure exactly how I can dyanmically call model name, so if I'm in `NewModel`, it will generate `new_model_crop_x`, and so forth

Comment: @sawa Please elaborate? That doesn't help me.

Comment: @andrewliu: well, I don't know `jcrop`, so I don't have an answer for you here.

Comment: where is this coffeescript located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

andrewliu. I don't what about dynamic model mean. I talk about how to use another model name to use jcrop.

```
update: (coords) =>
  $('#user_crop_x').val(coords.x)
  $('#user_crop_y').val(coords.y)
  $('#user_crop_w').val(coords.w)
  $('#user_crop_h').val(coords.h)
  @updatePreview(coords)
```

The `#user_crop_x` is come from this form:

```
= form_for MODEL, url: CROP_URL, method: :patch, html:{id: "jcrop_form"} do |f|
  - %w[x y w h].each do |attribute|
    = f.hidden_field "crop_#{attribute}"
  .form-actions
    = f.submit t(".crop"), class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

It will default generate many id in the hidden_field in rails's `form_for`. Just like `#user_crop_x` and `#user_crop_y` and so on.

The default id is a certain rule what is `##{model_name}_{attribute_name}`, so if you have `dynamic model` and the best way is set the class name in the hidden_field. Example:

```
= f.hidden_field "crop_#{attribute}", class: "crop_class_#{attribute}"
```

And set the jQuery code like:

```
update: (coords) =>
  $('.crop_class_x').val(coords.x)
  $('.crop_class_y').val(coords.y)
  $('.crop_class_w').val(coords.w)
  $('.crop_class_h').val(coords.h)
  @updatePreview(coords)
```

Comment: ahh okay, this is what kinda answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your coffeescript is rendered dynamically (ie in a view.js.erb file), then you can just use a shared variable like so:

**users_controller:**
Assign a shared variable that you can use in your view, for example:

`@user_name = User.find(1).name`

**view**

```
update: (coords) =>
  $('#<%= @user_name %>_crop_x').val(coords.x)
  $('#<%= @user_name %>_crop_y').val(coords.y)
  $('#<%= @user_name %>_crop_w').val(coords.w)
  $('#<%= @user_name %>_crop_h').val(coords.h)
  @updatePreview(coords)
```

Comment: my coffeescript file is in `app/assets/javascripts` is there a method that I can create or a helper and then call it in js file?

Comment: not possible because javascript is all executed client side. Any view helpers, model methods or templates in rails are processed server side. If you really want to make ruby variables available in your javascript files, i'd suggest using a gem called [paloma](https://github.com/kbparagua/paloma) which will allow you to do that.